# KeyError when calling dictionary items() function in python 2.7

Tags: python, dictionary

The following is the exception info:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 113, in items
    return [(key, self[key]) for key in self]
exceptions.KeyError: u'abc'
```

I suppose the key `abc` should not be appear if it is not in the dict, so that `for key in self` does not return `abc`

The code is like this:

```
ordered_dict = collections.OrderedDict()

... do something to add elements to ordered_dict

def foo():
    for k, b in ordered_dict.items():
        if time.time() - b > 10:
            del ordered_dict[k]
        else:
            twisted.internet.reactor.callLater(1, foo)

def bar(k):
    ordered_dict[k] = time.time()

... bar() is called constantly to add values, and foo() is called at the beginning of the program
```

Anything wrong in here? This `KeyError` happens randomly, not always.

python version 2.7.3
using `twisted` and `time` modules

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: @KlausD. Just posted. thanks for reply

Comment: deleting while iteration. It's wrong

Comment: more right ideom is - filtering. Or delete from copy. Or make deferred deletion: keep keys to delete, delete them at the the end as batch

Comment: Try with str(key) and self[str(key)]

Comment: You are iterating over your `dict` and deleting from it, which likely is the cause of this error if I had to guess.

Comment: What is the logic to delete your dictionary? I mean is the dictionary `ordered_dict` is available at file level for your deletion function? Have you tried `ordered_dict.pop(k, None)` ?

Comment: 1. I have not tried `pop`, but I'll give it a try @SijanBhandari
2. I think `items()` returns a copy of the dict, and I am iterating over the copy version. Isn't it ok to delete elements from the original dict? @Paul-AG      @juanpa.arrivillaga
3. Does str(key) make any difference? @Harsha

Comment: The error comes from calling 'items()', not inside the loop.

Comment: `items()` does not return copy of dictionary. It returns list of tuples. And, you can pop out dictionary item over iteration.

Comment: @SijanBhandari Then why the error was raised at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: Can you post your code here? You snippet is not  that clear. I want to see overall implementation.

Comment: @SijanBhandari just updated, this exception occurs once in a while, not constantly......

Comment: Have you tried `del ordered_dict[k]` with `ordered_dict.pop(k, None)`

Comment: Not before, I fixed it by using `keys()` instead of `items()` to iterate and use `pop()` to replace `del`.